# Difference in math between VB.Net and PHP

Tags: php, vb.net, math

I am porting my own VB.Net utility to PHP, which is used to extract meta-data info out of photos (EXIF) along with GPS Coords. The problem is that i get different results in PHP. I know the correct output is VB.Net's because i tested it with a photo taken in my home.

The math operations i use are

VB.Net

```
degrees + (minutes / 60) + (seconds / 3600)
```

PHP

```
$longDegreesResult + ($longMinutesResult / 60) + ($longSecondsResult / 3600)
```

But the results are not the same!
Is there any difference in PHP calculations, or any "rounding" of the numbers that i should know about?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the data types in VB.net?  Can you give us an example of values you'd enter for each of the three variables and what the results in each language are?

Comment: What **are** the results?

Comment: I do three divisions with standard values (which are GPS's dregrees, minutes and seconds) and then the operations that i posted above. In both situations the values i use for the math operations are the same. the results i get with VB.Net is 39.009354699999996,25.752712799999998 and with PHP is 39.643888888889,25.389722222222 (I changed the coords but kept the difference because they're my own coords)

Comment: @JohnDoe, give a value of `degrees`, `minutes`, and `seconds` that causes the difference.

Comment: 23/1 for degrees, 45/1 for minutes, 1031/100 for seconds (that's for longtitude for example)

Comment: What data type are you using in VB.NET? float? double?

Comment: Which answer is more correct?

Comment: I get the same (wrong) result with floatval()... none i guess :/

Comment: When you are having problems like this it is essential that you provide the complete code you are using - ideally an SSCCE http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215383/222049  @invisal's answer is an excellent example of the type of code you should provide - given that such test code produces reliable and correct answers there is obviously something else that you are doing to cause the problem.  Show us your code.

Answer (score 1):

This is the VB.NET code

```
Sub Main()
    Dim degrees As Double = 23 / 1
    Dim minutes As Double = 45
    Dim seconds As Double = 1031 / 100

    Console.WriteLine(degrees + (minutes / 60) + (seconds / 3600))
End Sub
```

And this is PHP code

```
$degrees = 23 / 1;
$minutes = 45;
$seconds = 1031 / 100;

$result = $degrees + ($minutes / 60) + ($seconds / 3600);

echo $result;
```

They print the same result:

```
23.752863888889
```

Comment: I literally just did this myself and found the same thing.

Comment: `$longDegrees = explode('/', $exif['GPS']['GPSLongitude'][0]);
$longMinutes = explode('/', $exif['GPS']['GPSLongitude'][1]);
$longSeconds = explode('/', $exif['GPS']['GPSLongitude'][2]);
$longDegreesResult = $longDegrees[0] / $longDegrees[1];
$longMinutesResult = $longMinutes[0] / $longMinutes[1];
$longSecondsResult = $longSeconds[0] / $longSeconds[1];
$longtitude = $longDegreesResult + ($longMinutesResult / 60) + ($longSecondsResult / 3600);` This is the LONGTITUDE calculation, the array's values are exactly the same with these i gave you...

Comment: And this is wrong `23.752863888889` that's what i get too. These are not my coords. From VB.Net i get `23.752712799999998` which are correct! (Checked in google maps)

Comment: @JohnDoe - invisal's answer above *is* what VB.NET also produces and it *is* the mathematically correct answer.  To produce the (incorrect) value of `23.752712799999998` the `seconds` value would need to be 9.76 and not 10.31.  Show us your VB code.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that PHP won't give me enough numbers AFTER comma. VB.Net shows from 1 to 2 more of them. Wtf... guys thank you all! I will try to find the reason PHP "cuts" the output. Thanks again!

EDIT:
The answer was `ini_set('precision', 20);`

Thank you all!